# how do i use slidetoggle and allow only one div open at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sumIx

```
$('.module article').hide();
});
$('.module-content, .module-photo').click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     $('.module article').slideUp();
  } $(this).parent().children('article').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

If you click on any of the boxes, the previously active div closes as expected.

When you try to close the same div which is active, it opens right back up. How do I keep everything else the same but correct the behavior so that it doesn't reopen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.module-content').click(function() {
   var $this = $(this).closest('section').find('article');
   $('.module article').not($this).slideUp();
   $this.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/DBirp

Comment: +1 for the `.closest()` and `.find()`, they are more resilient indeed in case OP adds more markup in between the article and section/div. My answer kept more of OP's original code. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Your answer is _fine_, in that case he can post another question :), _I'm joking_, +1 for using `not` and well commented code.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery iterates element collections naturally so your loops are irrelevant in this case. Here's the commented updated code:

```
$('.module-content').click(function() {
    //stores a reference to the clicked section's article
    var article = $(this).parent().children('article');
    //hides all other articles
    $('.module article').not(article).slideUp();
    //toggles the clicked one
    article.slideToggle('slow');
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgJDr